# Random.Choice() is returning entire string

Tags: python, random

I am trying to write a program that queries a word document and returns a line randomly from that document. Currently, every line from the document is being returned, even when I apply random.choice(). Any thoughts on how I can correct this?

I ran a len() on my list and confirmed it is returning multiple variables, but the entire list is still being returned.

---

```
 import random

 filename = 'happy document.txt'
 dictionary_list = []

 with open(filename) as file_object:
 lines = file_object.readlines()
   for l in lines: 
     lines = [l.strip('\n') for l in lines]
     dictionary_list.append(lines)

random_choice = random.choice(dictionary_list)
print(random_choice)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You append the whole list of lines to your `dictionary_list` on each loop, so whichever of its items you choose, it's the whole list...

You can do:

```
import random

filename = 'happy document.txt'
with open(filename) as file_object:
    lines = [line.strip('\n') for line in file_object]

random_choice = random.choice(lines)
print(random_choice)
```

As a side note, `for line in file_object` iterates on the lines of the file, you don't need to use `readlines` first and iterate again on the list of lines.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected I might be doing that, but wasn't sure how to stop it. Your output did resolve the issue. I notice your output is simpler than my line of thinking, too. I'll try to remember to watch for simpler options.

Comment: You're welcome! :) Note that when you feel that an answer solves your problem, you may accept it by clicking on the check mark on the left.

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
     dictionary_list.extend(lines)
```

to "un-nest" the `lines` into your dictionary_list.